# How can I group posts by date on frontpage?

Tags: posts

For example;

20 September 2014
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3

19 September 2014
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3

18 September 2014
Post 1
Post 2

Comment: Does is not do that right now.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. If you haven't done so, please read [ask] and visit the site's [tour] page. You should not ask your question in the title, but in the body of your post :-)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You test when the date changes and only show it once, right when it changed for the first time.

```
<?php
$date = 0;
$newDate = true;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :

    the_post();

    if ($date == 0)
        $date = the_date();
    else if ($date != the_date()) {
        $date = the_date();
        $newDate = true;
    }

    if ($newDate)
        echo $date . ' ';

    the_title();

    $newDate = false;

    /* rest of the code */

endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Please correct your syntax. Your code really has a lot of syntax errors :-)

Comment: And don't forget about `the_post();` :-)

Comment: Yea, no infinity loop for me! =D